# Jupyter runs terminal in virtual environment but ipynb in base python

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, conda

I am trying to run Jupyter in a conda virtual environment. I have activated my environment and if I run python from the terminal it runs the virtual environment correctly.

However if I launch jupyter from within my virtual environment (by opening a Windows command prompt, typing `conda activate hqb-api2` and then `jupyter lab --no-browser`), the .ipynb files are running a kernel using the base python installation rather than the virtual environment. You can see this by printing `sys.prefix`:

[image]

However, if I launch a terminal in Jupyter instead of a .ipynb file, then it correctly uses the virtual environment:

[image]

lastly, here is a subsection from `pip list` showing the relevant jupyter packages:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check `kernel.json`? You can try this two lines of code: `python -m pip install ipykernel

python -m ipykernel install --user`

Comment: `python -m ipykernel install --user1` fixed it. Can you explain what it does please?

Comment: Explained :). Hope uou got it!

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Comment: @darthbith sure, I can delete the images. But does any of that link really apply here? The images are just for convenience to better show the difference between the jupyter terminal & the regular terminal. All the relevant commands are already in the text (I say commands but it is literally only `sys.prefix`). The outputs in the pictures are showing paths local to my computer so they wouldn't be useful to anyone in the future in terms of searching. If the images are absent, the question is still understandable, not to mention this answer got exactly the right answer in very short time.

Comment: @Dan Personally, I think that anything that can be represented as plain text, should be, at the least for visually impaired users to be able to engage with the site. In this case, yes, searchability is maybe less important, but you never know what keywords will turn up. And there's no real reason to have them as images either... In any case, it's your post so do as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this documentation: [Installing the IPython kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#installing-the-ipython-kernel)

> However, if you want to use a kernel with a different version of Python, or in a virtualenv or conda environment, you’ll need to install that manually

Executing the following command will fix the issue.

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Comment: It looks like I have to run `python -m ipykernel install --user` every time I switch environments, is there a way to run it locally to a virtual environment?

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments

Comment: @Dan it is the same link which is given in the answer. The thing is there is section `Kernels for different environments` that you need to look for.

Comment: Did that sort your issue?

Comment: Yes thanks! But do you by any chance know how to remove one when I accidentally made one called myenv which doesn't actually exist

Comment: Are you talking about `myenv` being kernel? If yes, check for `myenv` using `jupyter kernelspec list` then if it is present `jupyter kernelspec remove myenv`

Comment: yes, thanks, exactly that! I accidentally hit enter after pasting the example in the link. thanks again!

Comment: Did you remove `myenv`?